# Definition of principal series representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I can’t seem to find a complete definition of the principal series representations of a Lie group that doesn’t assume too much. Assume I know all the various decompositions (Iwasawa, Levi, etc.) and whatever you want about finite-dimensional representations. Where can I find a definition?

Comment: Did you try Knapp's books? For instance, here: http://www.math.utah.edu/~ptrapa/Knapp-Trapa.pdf

Comment: That helps! Thank you!